# How to create a View with a contextual filter (fixed) value form a field value?

Tags: views

I'm creating a dynamic View with the following aspects:

1) A content-type of 'product'.

2) A content-type of 'company'.

3) A User who works for a company, linked to a compagny by a user_compagny_field.

- A User can only sell the products linked to his/her company.
- All products are linked by field 'products solds in this compagny'.

I've created a View that correctly shows all products. When I enter the NID from company X (3 in my case) i get the correct products: 10 and 7.

How do I get the value from the User-field compagny as an Contextual-filter inside my view. As far i can see I've three options:

1) Fixed Value: which works if I enter the Value of 3).

2) User ID from logged in User, doesn't work because i'm user 1. And I need the value of my compagny field.

3) Content ID from URL.

I find it rather complex and I'm always struggling with contextual Filters.
Thank you for your time and kind words, keep on Drupalling.

Comment: I've solved my own problem a bit differently, that I expected:

I've added this module: drupal.org/viewfield, and added the View inside the 'company' content-type. Used tokens to pass the NID of the company to the view as an argument.

For me this way works. When I visit the node of company X, i only see the connected products. When I use AJAX i can even place those in seperate blocks. In that case I don't need the full page View.

Comment: If you have entity reference on your Company content type, that references all Product nodes, doesn't that field show the links to those Products, right there on the Company node page? Why do you also need a block on Company page with the contextual filter that does the same as the field? To filter additionally based on the user viewing the page?

Comment: Exactly that, I didn't want to show all products, but only the products the users of that company was allowed to view. There for I needed a contextual filter with as argument de UID. Maybe is posible with a lot of relations and contextual filtering in Views, but this solution just worked fine. An alternative would have been using the EVA-module (https://www.drupal.org/project/eva). But problem solved.